# Which happens first: OnCollisionStay() or LateUpdate()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to instantiate an object with a collider, check its collisions, then if its not touching anything, delete it.

is the following code always guaranteed to execute it the right order? (ie: collisions THEN lateUpdate?)

```
public class RemoveIfColliding : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool touching = false;

    private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
    {
        print("I am touching " + collision.other.name);
        touching = true;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!touching)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes if you call it in the right order `OnCollisionStay()` `LateUpdate()`

Comment: @Jee Mok ... yes .. I guess the question was in which order do they get called ^^ .. this is Unity3D specific and those methods are called by messages from the Engine not by OP

Comment: I see... sorry for not understanding the question!

Comment: Do you want this check continuously or only once in the moment you instantiate the object?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Order of Execution for Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html):

I would intepret it as all messages from the `Physics` block are called before the `GameLogic`. It states

> The physics cycle might happen more than once per frame if the fixed time step is less than the actual frame update time.

but they should still be done before the `Update` and `LateUpdate` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Even if LateUpdate is called first, the object will be destroyed in its next iteration. So basically at seemengly the same time.

But I don't think this is the best way to do it. You can simplify the code by not using the late update and the boolean at all. Just do it like this:

```
public class RemoveIfColliding : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
    {
        print("I am touching " + collision.other.name);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP want's to **not** destroy if touching - else destroy

Comment: My bad didn't understand completely. In that case you can just use the function OnCollisionExit()

Comment: I don't think so ... OP seems to want to make this check only in the moment the object is instantiated